# String to Hex Short java

Tags: java, string, hex, short

I have a variable define as

```
short s1 = 0x3039;
```

to do some operation, converting it to string

```
String ss = Integer.toHexString(s1 & 0xffff);
```

which give result as string "3039". After some string operation it is converted to string "3130". Now i want it back as

```
short s2 = 0x3130;
```

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Short.parseShort` with 16 as radix

```
Short.parseShort(yourHexString, 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
short s2 = Short.valueOf(ss2).shortValue();
```